# How to correctly define a fabricator that ex_machina's `params_for` recognises?

Tags: testing, elixir

I started on a test that should verify that the fabricated objects are valid.
But even though I have defined a `practitioner_factory`, it does not find it.
Any idea why?
`practitioner_factory!` works when I manually run it from iex.

```
  1 defmodule Booking.PractitionersTest do
  2   use ExUnit.Case, async: true
  3   use Booking.DataCase
  4   use ExMachina.Ecto
  5   alias Ecto.Changeset
  6   alias Booking.Factory
  7

 22     test "is valid from the factory" do
 23       new_practitioner = params_for(:practitioner)
 24       changeset = Practitioner.changeset(Practitioner, new_practitioner)
 25       assert changeset.valid?
 26     end
```

It crashes with the following stack trace:

```
  1) test practitioners is valid from the factory (Booking.PractitionersTest)
     test/booking/practitioners_test.exs:22
     ** (ExMachina.UndefinedFactoryError) No factory defined for :practitioner.

     Please check for typos or define your factory:

         def practitioner_factory do
           ...
         end

     code: new_practitioner = params_for(:practitioner)
     stacktrace:
       (ex_machina 2.7.0) lib/ex_machina.ex:243: ExMachina.build/3
       (ex_machina 2.7.0) lib/ex_machina/ecto.ex:127: ExMachina.Ecto.params_for/3
       test/booking/practitioners_test.exs:23: (test)
```

Here's my `lib/booking/factory.ex`

```
  1 defmodule Booking.Factory do
  2   # with Ecto
  3   use ExMachina.Ecto, repo: Booking.Repo
  4
  5   alias Booking.Practitioners.Practitioner
  6   alias Booking.Products.Product
  7   alias Booking.Repo
  8
  9   def practitioner_factory do
 10     %Practitioner{
 11       first_name: Faker.Person.first_name(),
 12       last_name: Faker.Person.last_name()
 13     }
 14   end

 23   def practitioner_factory! do
 24     practitioner_factory()
 25     |> Repo.insert()
 26   end
```

Comment: Do you need to specify the repo? `use ExMachina.Ecto, repo: MyApp.Repo`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the path where you have defined the factory it looks like it's not in the `test` folder. If you don't need to use the factory in other environments, you can add it inside `test/support` so that it is only compiled in the test environment.

Also, be sure to start the application in your `test/test_helper.exs` before ExUnit.start, using:

```
{:ok, _} = Application.ensure_all_started(:ex_machina)
```

Looking at your test file, you have:

```
  1 defmodule Booking.PractitionersTest do
  2   use ExUnit.Case, async: true
  3   use Booking.DataCase
  4   use ExMachina.Ecto
  5   alias Ecto.Changeset
  6   alias Booking.Factory

...
 23       new_practitioner = params_for(:practitioner)
```

As you're not doing something like `Factory.params_for(:practitioner)` (from the `alias Booking.Factory`), you need to do something like `import Booking.Factory` in line 6, otherwise that factory is not defined in your test file.

Also, you probably don't need line 4 `use ExMachina.Ecto` as that is already defined in line 3 of `lib/booking/factory.ex`.